# coredata : join query operations

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

[image]i have to use following query for fetching the data from two entity. 
**SELECT * FROM Guides AS t1 JOIN Guide_Category_Int AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.guide_id**
i know that we can't use coredata as sqlite so for that i made relationship between these two entity and used following code but not able to get results.

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityname inManagedObjectContext:kAppDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

 NSString* predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id== %@"];//**in that line how should i use predicate for getting result**

 fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];

 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

 [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:TOTAL_BATCH_COUNT];

 NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:kAppDelegate.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    fetchedResultsController_.delegate = self;

    return fetchedResultsController_;
```

Answer (score 0):

"JOIN"-s are not supported in Core-Data ,

It will return the Entities , but as I can see it has a relation , so You will get Guides which has property Guide_Category ,

What query do you want to execute after joining ? Where ... ?

if you use this predicate , you will filter with ID of the given entity ( in our case Guide-s ID )

```
NSString* predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id== %@"];
```

do you want to filter by category id ? then use following and it will return only Guides which has category with that id

```
NSString* predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ANY guide.category_id == %@"];
```

Comment: first i have to join then filter the result i am not understanding how to join both entity.anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: the Join is done automatically by core data , when you fetch "Guides" entity , it will automatically fetch its "Guide_Category_Int" when you access that field

Comment: i tried this but not getting any result and using the same query in sqlite getting the results.NSString* predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ANY guide.category_id == %@",categoryid];